# Trigger second workflow on change of First workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a list where i have created two workflow first worfklow will start manually and on change the status to complete after that i want to start second workflow on same list

Comment: Are you using SharePoint designer 2013 workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to your scenario:

In both cases, You need to:

1. Create one **Status** column.
2. Update its value to **Complete** at the end of first workflow.
3. Run your 2nd workflow with the trigger as **start the workflow automatically when an item is changed**.

**Solution 1**:

You can use **Wait for Field Change in Current Item** action to check if **status is equal to complete**.

Then you can run rest of the action in your workflow.

**Solution 2**:

You can use **IF Condition** action to check if **status is equal to complete**.

Then you can run rest of the action in **If condition block** else you can End/Terminate workflow.

**References**:

1. [How to start a workflow when a value in specific column is changed?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7eddf7c3-1dec-4369-8995-ec7a6123a70d/how-to-start-a-workflow-when-a-value-in-specific-column-is-changed?forum=sharepointcustomization)

**Note**: If you want to run SharePoint 2013 workflow from another SharePoint 2013 workflow then it is not possible. However you can run **SharePoint 2010 workflow from another SharePoint 2013 workflow**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's **not possible** to check status of another workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013.

- For a workaround you can create a field in your List/Library and assign some default value to it.
- Now, when 1st workflow is about to complete, change this column value.
- Run your 2nd workflow when an item is changed and check if that field is changed.
- If it satisfies your condition(field value changed), perform the actions.

I hope this helps.